# Get/Read Indexed Item of WPF C# Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am begginer in WPF C#. 
I used a Combobox that fill with a Model of Linq to SQL. This is worked correct .
But I have a Big simple problem with this . In my Application first get count of Combobox members and then generate a Random index ( within 0 – Count-1 ) and set combobox index programically .
Combobox show Indexed Item content correctly , But can not get content of Indexed Item and show in Textbox or etc .
When I try get indexed item , I get Class name contain Linq to Sql Model and Table name . ( Same as Myclass.tblHeader )
Of course ! I searched my problrm extremely But don’t found answer . I read and exam many codes from sites and this site , But my problem don’t solve yet .
By the way , I found one answer that work with "DropDownClosed" event that working excellent .
But My problem focused on Combobox loaded! or Form loaded! .
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: SelectedItem will give you the item, then you can use desired property.

Comment: XAML Code :

<ComboBox Name="cmbHeader" SelectedValuePath="Content" SelectionChanged="cmbHeader_SelectionChanged" DropDownClosed="cmbHeader_DropDownClosed" Loaded="cmbHeader_Loaded"/>

Comment: Behind Code :

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            cmbHeader_Fill();
            cmbFooter_Fill();
            .
   .
   .
        }

        private void cmbHeader_Fill()
        {
            cmbHeader.ItemsSource = DB.HeaderFooter.Where(c => c.GroupMessage == 1).ToList();
            cmbHeader.DisplayMemberPath = "BodyMessage";
        }

Comment: private void cmbFooter_Fill()
        {
            cmbFooter.ItemsSource = DB.HeaderFooter.Where(c => c.GroupMessage == 2).ToList();
            cmbFooter.DisplayMemberPath = "BodyMessage";            
        }

        private void cmbHeader_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
     // This is working and return Indexed Item content            
     tbxDebug.Text = (cmbHeader.Text) + " ..... " + cmbHeader.SelectedIndex.ToString();
        }

Comment: private void cmbHeader_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
     // This is not working and return ClassOfModel.tbl.HeaderFooter
     tbxDebug.Text = (cmbHeader.Text) + " ..... " + cmbHeader.SelectedIndex.ToString();
        }

    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally this should work to get the selected items

```
String mySelectedItem = myComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

or

```
String mySelectedItem = myComboBox.Text;
```

Comment: ! thanks for replay . I examin second choice befor  and dont get answer . about Choice one  , what is Combobox ? Is this c# reserved word ? or yhis is my combobox or instance of it ?

Comment: its your combobox. If your combobox's name is "mycombobox" then you have to replace ComboBox by mycombobox. I have updated my code.

Comment: ! Thanks Again for help . 
 
Your first code returns Error that instance not set to object .
 
 But strange happenstane  your second code works excelent  and can get combox content .
 
 very strange! I used this code for several times within last week and got error , But now its working . 
 
Great answer and Thank you very much !